# why there is an icon on the lower left quarter of my screen after I minimized my window?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I set a full screen && Frameless window by QML, and also I do not want to display the window icon on the toolbar, my window settings is as bellow:

```
id: root
color: "#dededc"
visible: true
flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
opacity: 0.8
title: qsTr("my demo")
visibility: "FullScreen"
```

at first, it's good to me, there is no window icon, and it's full screen.

however after I minimize the window, the issue is coming, I get an icon on the lower left quarter of my screen, how can I remove/not show the icon?

can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Don't minimize the window. Set `root.visibility = Window.Hidden` instead of call `root.showMinimized()`.

Comment: cool, thanks, @mcchu